# Angular - performance issue when toggling a CSS class

Tags: css, angular

I'm building a datepicker in Angular and I have a performance issue with toggling a CSS class.

I want to highlight the day, which is today, and for this purpose I am toggling a CSS class using the following statement in HTML:

```
<div class="calendar__days">
  <div *ngFor="let day of daysOfCurrentMonth" [class.today]="isToday(day)">{{ day }}</div>
</div>
```

`isToday(day)` is a method, which returns a boolean value:

```
  isToday(day: number) {
    return day === new Date().getDate()
      && this.date.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()
      && this.date.getFullYear() === new Date().getFullYear();
  }
```

In theory, this works pretty well. Now, here is the problem: When changing the current month, `this.date.getMonth()` is decremented by 1 - `isToday()` will, therefore, return false for each of the displayed days. This seems to happen very slowly though: All the days are changed according to the new month and the number, which equals the day of today, is still highlighted as today for around .2s - enough time for me to see the highlighted day and be confused about it.

That's why I wonder if there is a way to toggle a CSS class instantly. I think if I toggle the class, first thing, upon changing the month, I might not run into this issue.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Your problem is probably the fact that you’re calling a function from your template (which isn’t ideal).  Angular calls your isToday function every change detection cycle (which could be multiple times per second). You probably want to come up with a better way.. maybe pre-process you loop to include the isToday flag in your component?

Comment: Without having the full context of the component I can think of three possible performance degradation causes - 1. You have three new Date() calls, you can reduce it to one. 2. The component is re-rendered too often and the function gets called many times per second - use ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush. 3. The CSS style that you're toggling is expensive (layout calculations).

Comment: thx you two for your comments! @MikeOne : What do you mean by `preprocessing`? I can add a boolean variable `isToday` in my component, but at some point I will have to set it, right? How can I achieve this without calling a method?

Comment: You can add a property to day (isToday?) maybe? Then in your template you can simply do [class.today]="day.isToday”

Comment: ah ok, well... I don't have a day-component - it's just a simple div-tag inside the HTML of my datepicker-component.  Otherwise you are right, this might work. Do you think I can still do sth like this without having an extra day-component?

Comment: @TsvetanGanev : It seems to be mainly due to layout calculations: The CSS class that I toggle is painting a background color for a small div-container. When only drawing a border instead, I don't have this annoying delay. I really want to draw the background color though. So I wonder: The only thing that happens when switching the month or year of my calendar, is that the text inside my div-container changes. Is there a way to slow done changing this text? Because If I could slow down this change, Angular would have enough time to draw my background color, right?